# How to choose value for serviceStatus.dwWaitHint?

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

I am following this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx to create a windows service. I have a class called `TaskManager` which uses Quartz.Net to manage a bunch of jobs. It has `.Go()` (which doesn't block) and `.Stop()` methods. If I've understood correctly, all I need to do in my service is

```
    private TaskManager _taskManager;

    public DataPumpService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _taskManager = new TaskManager();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _taskManager.Go();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _taskManager.Stop();
    }
```

But then the tutorial has a section on setting the service status. It doesn't really explain what the service status is or when I would want to set it. `TaskManager.Stop()` can take a few seconds to finish (internally it call `IScheduler.Interrupt()` on all jobs and then `IScheduler.Shutdown(true)`). So should I be setting statuses? If so then assuming I include the code in sections (1), (2) and (3) from the Setting Service Status section of [the tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx), is it correct to do the following (essentially for both methods in my first code block above):

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // Update the service state to Stop Pending.
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING;
        serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

        _taskManager.Stop();

        // Update the service state to Running.
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOPPED;
        SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
    }
```

If this is right, then is the `serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;` property something I need to choose wisely or is that default value a good thing to stick with? Essentially I have no idea what this value is for...

Comment: Hmm, not sure how that made it into that MSDN article.  The way the ServiceBase class already takes care of the service status is good enough in 99.9% of the cases.  Including this dwWaitHint, it is wrapped by the ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime() method.  You should not need it, 30 seconds is good enough to get 99.9% of all services started :)  Note that none of the versions of this article prior to 4.5 talk about it at all.

Comment: @HansPassant so are you saying that if I just use my first block of code and don't mess with the serviceStatus at all - it is generally fine? Also what do you mean by 30 seconds... is that a default or are you suggesting I use 30000 instead of 100000?

Comment: Don't mess with it.  30 seconds is the default timeout that Windows uses.

Comment: Thanks! Please add as an asnwer

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest checking out the Topshelf project that makes the whole windows services story a whole lot easier http://topshelf-project.com/ . Quartz.NET also includes a sample of this in the Quartz.Server project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [@HansPassant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) says

> The way the ServiceBase class already takes care of the service status
> is good enough in 99.9% of the cases.
> You should not need it, 30 seconds (the default) is good enough to get 99.9% of all services
> started/stopped.

But if you need to handle a long running close, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996(v=vs.85).aspx) says concerning

> **dwWaitHint**
>
> The estimated time required for a pending start, stop,
> pause, or continue operation, in milliseconds. Before the specified
> amount of time has elapsed, the service should make its next call to
> the SetServiceStatus function with either an incremented dwCheckPoint
> value or a change in dwCurrentState. If the amount of time specified
> by dwWaitHint passes, and dwCheckPoint has not been incremented or
> dwCurrentState has not changed, the service control manager or service
> control program can assume that an error has occurred and the service
> should be stopped. However, if the service shares a process with other
> services, the service control manager cannot terminate the service
> application because it would have to terminate the other services
> sharing the process as well.

and

> **dwCheckPoint**
>
> The check-point value the service increments periodically
> to report its progress during a lengthy start, stop, pause, or
> continue operation. For example, the service should increment this
> value as it completes each step of its initialization when it is
> starting up. The user interface program that invoked the operation on
> the service uses this value to track the progress of the service
> during a lengthy operation. This value is not valid and should be zero
> when the service does not have a start, stop, pause, or continue
> operation pending.

This clarifies the footnote in the [walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The Service Control Manager uses the dwWaitHint and dwCheckpoint
> members of the SERVICE_STATUS structure to determine how much time to
> wait for a Windows Service to start or shut down. If your OnStart and
> OnStop methods run long, your service can request more time by calling
> SetServiceStatus again with an incremented dwCheckPoint value.

Based on that, I wrote my Stop code like such. Note that, I run some very long tasks and terminating them is really not a good idea hence the lengthy wait times.

```
//set the status to pending close
var serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus
{
    dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING,
    dwWaitHint = 120000//two minutes wait time
};
SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);

Engine.Cancel();

while (Engine.IsRunning())
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint++;//updating the checkpoint so I don't get terminated
    SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if you add a section to the top of this answer that specifies what Hans Passant said in the comments, i.e. in 99.9% of the cases you should just leave the defaults, I'll be happy to accept this.

Comment: Added it. Thanks. It actually makes it a way better.