# WIX Service Installer

Tags: wix, serviceinstall

I am using WIX Installer to install my service. I have configured the installer to install and start the service post installation.

Please find the configuration.

ServiceInstall Id="ABCServiceInstall" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"                     Name="ABCAssignment" DisplayName="Display Assignment"                         Description="Servie Description." Start="auto"                        Interactive="no" Account="[ACCOUNT]" Password="[PASSWORD]"                        ErrorControl="ignore"

ServiceControl Id="ABCAssignmentStart" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="ABCAssignment" Wait="no"

The service get installed and started properly. No issue. 
However, if I try with the wrong password, It tries to start the service 7 times, (or may be up to that the credentials got locked). 
It is the same case, even if I put Yes or no for the wait attribute in ServiceControl.

I have default service recovery configuration. No recovery option specified exclusively.

Is there anyway that I can limit the number of tries to start the service.

Comment: Just a comment, but maybe have a look at the section ["Managed Service Accounts" in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375540/129130). Essentially avoiding passwords to maintain.

Comment: [PhilDW is a service expert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356775/129130). Just want to link to his answer so you have something to start with. Maybe also check the "Links" section in my answer in the same "thread" as PhilDW's answer.