# Service is failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start the system services

Tags: .net-core, wix

I am using VS2019 and i have converted my windows service to .netcore 3.1 and created installer file using  WIX. I was able to install the service and while starting the service manualy it works, but when starting automatically after installation getting an error like

***Service is failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start the system services***

My Coponent code is below,

```
<ServiceInstall
              Id="ServiceInstaller"
              Type="ownProcess"
              Vital="yes"
              Name="Django_DRAProcessorServiceTest"
              DisplayName="Django_DRAProcessorServiceTest"
              Description="Django_DRAProcessorServiceTest"
              Start="auto"
              Interactive="no"
              ErrorControl="normal" >

          <util:PermissionEx User="Authenticated Users"
              ServiceStart="yes"
              ServiceStop="yes"
              ServicePauseContinue="yes"
              ServiceInterrogate="yes"
              ServiceChangeConfig="yes"
              ServiceEnumerateDependents="yes"
              ServiceQueryConfig="yes"
              ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
              ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes" />
          <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart"  SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" />
        </ServiceInstall>      
      <ServiceControl Id="Django_DRAProcessorService_Start"
            Name="Django_DRAProcessorService"
            Start="install"
            Wait="no" />        
            <ServiceControl Id="Django_DRAProcessorService_Stop"
            Name="Django_DRAProcessorService"
            Stop="uninstall"
            Remove="uninstall"`enter code here`
            Wait="yes" />
```

I have also given elevated privilages. Is there anything that i need to do or a`enter code here`nything missing.

Comment: Did you run the installer as an administrator? Under which/what type of account are you trying to run the service?

Comment: [Here is a link collection on deployment issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864). Also, maybe try these service check lists: [Overall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149858/129130), [Detailed 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530377/129130), [Detailed 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637913/129130) - what is that authenticated users section? What account runs the service? This sounds like a policy issue or a lacking privilege to deal with services. `LocalSystem` should have all necessary privilege.

Comment: [This was the intended link actually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55087943/129130). The MSI runs some operations in system context. Your use of that authenticated users construct must cause some side-effect. Try to take it out and see what happens?

Comment: Finally issue is resolved, it is because of the name i given for ServiceInstall and ServiceControl was different. It should be same i have corrected and issue is resolved.